# How do I pan in Blender using a Wacom 3D Pen?

Tags: 3d-view, hardware

I've just got a Wacom 3D pen for sculpting in blender and in the video Wacom released for the pen it shows you can navigate without using the keyboard:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tcIVpiK3TXw

The first button is rotating the view like the middle mouse button and the second one in set for pan/zoom. Now, it is zooming when you click the button and move your hand while hovering over the screen, and the dragging, as the video suggests, is supposed to happen when clicking that button and tapping the screen with the pen tip.

The problem is that it is not dragging (or panning). (I cant find anywhere in the Wacom settings to control the hover and click/touch and click gestures)

Also, it is not a special feature for the 3D pen, it should work like this with all pens (it is working as shown in the video in Solidworks with the default settings).

Answer (score 4):

You just have to emulate a 3 button mouse. Here's how to do it:

1. Go to the *User Preferences*.
2. Go to the *Input* tab.
3. Check *Emulate 3 button mouse*.
4. Hit *Save User Settings*.

From here on out you can rotate the view using <kbd>Alt</kbd> + click and dragging, zoom using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + click and finally navigate using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> + click.

Comment: l'm not sure you understood me, it didn't solve the problem . I need to navigate using only the buttons and the feature i'm missing is panning,which supposed to be clicking and tapping with the stylus, like the video..or maybe I misunderstood you and if so, what did I get wrong? do I need to change blender pan shortkeys somehow?

Comment: The last combo for panning should be `ALT+SHIFT+click` (stylus down). Basically ALT is used to emulate the middle mouse button, then all the commands are the same as with the mouse. Nothing = orbit, CTRL = zoom, SHIFT = pan.

Answer (score 1):

you might have changed your shortcuts for 3d navigation in blender and that is screwing up sculpting part, to resolve these you can see your 3d navigation shortcuts in blender and map those functions on wacom .

I have setup my navigation close to 3ds max , which are 
Pan         - Middle mouse
rotate view - Alt + Middle mouse
zoom        - Track pad / Ctrl + Alt + Middle Mouse
after emulate a 3 mouse button for sculpting , you can map these functions into your wacom . For me these works 
Pan          - Alt + Click
Rotate View  - Alt + (pen first button - mapped as middle mouse )
Zoom         - Ctrl + Alt +Shift + Click / Ctrl + Alt + Middle Mouse(pen button)

Answer (score 0):

By default on my simple wacom tablet with blender 2.91 I have:

1. Shift + Pen click + Drag = pan
2. Ctrl + Pen click + Drag up/down = zoom
3. Pen click = rotate view.